# Transferring files applications via USB on Mac

Tags: nexus-5, file-transfer, macos

I have Nexus 5 and I'm using the Android File Transfer as explained on Google's official support: [Transfer files between your computer and Android device](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2840804).

However, after either copying zip archives or creating new folders in the file transfer window with my Nexus 5 connected via USB, I do not see the changes reflected on the device.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where in the storage are you copying files to, and how are you looking for them on the Nexus 5?

Comment: Which file manager are you using on the Nexus 5?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using the android File transfer program from http://www.android.com/filetransfer as that is the best way to transfer files on OSX.

If you just drag files into that directory it opens by default, the files might not show. On the "Android File Transfer" App choose the "Download" directory which is the best place to store a file, then drag files into that directory. This directory is accessible by all programs that have access to the internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is [Handshake](https://www.smartisan.com/apps/#/handshaker)

can use both WIFI or USB.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.